# How do I set ToolbarItem to the left in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to set a ToolbarItem on the left of the navigation bar, but I don't know how to set it up. The default ToolbarItem for Xamarin.Forms is on the right

Comment: On a specific platform? You will need a custom renderder for this, because like you said; it is not supported by default

Answer (score 0):

In iOS I use a custom renderer for this and I don't think there's any way around it. In Android I don't really bother because people are used to the items being on the right hand side. The renderer below checks if there are more than 1 ToolBarItems and if so moves one over to the left hand side.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(LeftNavigationItemRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS
{
    public class LeftNavigationItemRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            if (NavigationController == null)
                return;

            var navigationItem = NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;
            var leftNativeButtons = (navigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems ?? new UIBarButtonItem[] { }).ToList();
            var rightNativeButtons = (navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems ?? new UIBarButtonItem[] { }).ToList();

            if (rightNativeButtons.Count > 1)
            {
                var nativeItem = rightNativeButtons.Last();
                rightNativeButtons.Remove(nativeItem);
                leftNativeButtons.Add(nativeItem);
            }

            navigationItem.RightBarButtonItems = rightNativeButtons.ToArray();
            navigationItem.LeftBarButtonItems = leftNativeButtons.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to implement it in Xamarin.Forms, rather than on a particular platform, iOS or Android.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not how Xamarin Forms works. There are things that are simply not possible without resorting to platform-specific code and this is one of those things. Out of the box Xamarin Forms is limited in what it can do but it is very powerful when it comes to extensibility. That does mean that you're mostly going to have to write platform-specific code..